# Problems with SNMP Pass-Persist calling a C# program on ARM Linux

Tags: linux, snmp, net-snmp

This is net-snmp on ARM Linux, calling a C# program using the pass_persist. My snmpd.conf looks like this:

```
agentAddress udp:161
engineIDType 3

syslocation "My Location"
syscontact "root@unknown"

rocommunity public
rwcommunity private

view all included .1.3.6.1.4.1.12345

pass_persist .1.3.6.1.4.1.12345.999.1 /usr/share/test/TestSnmpResponder
```

I also tried with the following line:

```
pass_persist .1.3.6.1.4.1.12345 /usr/share/test/TestSnmpResponder
```

The responder works fine in the command line (sending `PING` results in `PONG`, and responds to all the requests with a fixed integer number just as a test.

When I start the net-snmp daemon, I get the following in the log:

```
/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf: line 12: Warning: Unknown token: pass_persist.
NET-SNMP version 5.9
```

It then responds to SNMP requests normally, but does not call or load the pass_persist program. I get the same error if I replace `pass_persist` with `pass` just as a test.

Just for completeness, the C# code is:

```
   internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            File.AppendAllText("log.txt", $"Started daemon");

            using (var inputStream = Console.OpenStandardInput())
            using (var strStream = new StreamReader(inputStream))
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    var command = strStream.ReadLine()!;
                    
                    switch (command.ToUpper())
                    {
                        case "":
                            //Tells the system to stop and quit
                            Environment.ExitCode = 0;
                            Environment.Exit(0);
                            break;
                        case "PING":
                            Console.WriteLine("PONG");
                            break;
                        case "GET":
                            string oid = strStream.ReadLine()!;
                            File.AppendAllText("log.txt", $"GET {oid}");
                            Console.WriteLine("integer");
                            Console.WriteLine("998877");
                            break;
                        case "GETNEXT":
                        case "SET":
                        default:
                            break;

                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Am I missing some kind of configuration in the net-snmp configuration during build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently this was a problem with Buildroot's default configuration. To diagnose the problem, I ran the following command:

```
snmpd -Dmib_init -H
```

Which produced the following output of "understandable" directives:

```
Configuration directives understood:   In snmpd.conf and snmpd.local.conf:
    authtrapenable           1 | 2              (1 = enable, 2 = disable)
    trapsink                 [-profile p] [-name n] [-tag t] host [community] [port]
    trap2sink                [-profile p] [-name n] [-tag t] host [community] [port]
    informsink               [-profile p] [-name n] [-tag t] host [community] [port]
    trapsess                 [-profile p] [-name n] [-tag t] [snmpcmdargs] host
    trapcommunity            community-string
    v1trapaddress            string
    agentuser                userid
    agentgroup               groupid
    agentaddress             SNMP bind address
    quit                     (1|yes|true|0|no|false)
    leave_pidfile            (1|yes|true|0|no|false)
    dontLogTCPWrappersConnects (1|yes|true|0|no|false)
    maxGetbulkRepeats        integerValue
    maxGetbulkResponses      integerValue
    avgBulkVarbindSize       integerValue
    pduStatsMax              integerValue
    pduStatsThreshold        integerValue
    injectHandler            injectHandler NAME INTONAME [BEFORE_OTHER_NAME]
    table                    tableoid
    add_row                  table_name indexes... values...
    agentxsocket             AgentX bind address
    agentxRetries            AgentX Retries
    agentxTimeout            AgentX Timeout (seconds)
    master                   specify 'agentx' for AgentX support
    agentxperms              AgentX socket permissions: socket_perms [directory_perms [username|userid [groupname|groupid]]]
    com2sec                  [-Cn CONTEXT] secName IPv4-network-address[/netmask] community
    com2sec6                 [-Cn CONTEXT] secName IPv6-network-address[/netmask] community
    com2secunix              [-Cn CONTEXT] secName sockpath community
    certSecName              certSecName PRIORITY FINGERPRINT [--shaNN|md5] <--sn SECNAME | --rfc822 | --dns | --ip | --cn | --any>
    snmpTlstmParams          snmpTlstmParams targetParamsName hashType:fingerPrint
    snmpTlstmAddr            snmpTlstmAddr targetAddrName hashType:fingerprint serverIdentity
    group                    name v1|v2c|usm|... security
    access                   name context model level prefix read write notify
    setaccess                name context model level prefix viewname viewval
    view                     name type subtree [mask]
    authcommunity            authtype1,authtype2 community [default|hostname|network/bits [oid|-V view [context]]]
    authuser                 authtype1,authtype2 [-s secmodel] user [noauth|auth|priv [oid|-V view [context]]]
    authgroup                authtype1,authtype2 [-s secmodel] group [noauth|auth|priv [oid|-V view [context]]]
    authaccess               name authtype1,authtype2 [-s secmodel] group view [noauth|auth|priv [context|context*]]
    rwcommunity              community [default|hostname|network/bits [oid|-V view [context]]]
    rocommunity              community [default|hostname|network/bits [oid|-V view [context]]]
    rwcommunity6             community [default|hostname|network/bits [oid|-V view [context]]]
    rocommunity6             community [default|hostname|network/bits [oid|-V view [context]]]
    rwuser                   user [noauth|auth|priv [oid|-V view [context]]]
    rouser                   user [noauth|auth|priv [oid|-V view [context]]]
    createUser               username [-e ENGINEID] (MD5|SHA|SHA-512|SHA-384|SHA-256|SHA-224|default) authpassphrase [(DES|AES|default) [privpassphrase]]
    dlmod                    module-name module-path
    sysdescr                 description
    syslocation              location
    syscontact               contact-name
    sysname                  node-name
    sysservices              NUMBER
    sysobjectid              OID
    skipNFSInHostResources   (1|yes|true|0|no|false)
    realStorageUnits         (1|yes|true|0|no|false)
    storageUseNFS            1 | 2              (1 = enable, 2 = disable)
    count_kthreads           0|1    0 to exclude kernel threads from hrSystemProcesses.0
    ignoredisk               name
    interface                name type speed
    ifmib_max_num_ifaces     IF-MIB MAX Number of ifaces
    include_ifmib_iface_prefix IF-MIB iface names included
    defDomain                application domain
    defTarget                application domain target
    sourceFilterType         none|acceptlist|blocklist
    sourceFilterAddress      host
    engineID                 string
    engineIDType             num
    engineIDNic              string
    interface_fadeout        interface_fadeout seconds
    interface_replace_old    interface_replace_old yes|no   In snmp.conf and snmp.local.conf:
    extraX509SubDir          string
    x509CRLFile              string
    tlsAlgorithms            string
    localCert                string
    peerCert                 string
    alias                    NAME TRANSPORT_DEFINITION
    doDebugging              (1|0)
    debugTokens              token[,token...]
    debugLogLevel            (emerg|alert|crit|err|warning|notice|info|debug)
    logTimestamp             (1|yes|true|0|no|false)
    logOption                string
    mibdirs                  [mib-dirs|+mib-dirs|-mib-dirs]
    mibs                     [mib-tokens|+mib-tokens]
    mibfile                  mibfile-to-read
    showMibErrors            (1|yes|true|0|no|false)
    commentToEOL             (1|yes|true|0|no|false)
    strictCommentTerm        (1|yes|true|0|no|false)
    mibAllowUnderline        (1|yes|true|0|no|false)
    mibWarningLevel          integerValue
    mibReplaceWithLatest     (1|yes|true|0|no|false)
    printNumericEnums        (1|yes|true|0|no|false)
    printNumericOids         (1|yes|true|0|no|false)
    escapeQuotes             (1|yes|true|0|no|false)
    dontBreakdownOids        (1|yes|true|0|no|false)
    quickPrinting            (1|yes|true|0|no|false)
    numericTimeticks         (1|yes|true|0|no|false)
    oidOutputFormat          integerValue
    suffixPrinting           integerValue
    extendedIndex            (1|yes|true|0|no|false)
    printHexText             (1|yes|true|0|no|false)
    printValueOnly           (1|yes|true|0|no|false)
    dontPrintUnits           (1|yes|true|0|no|false)
    hexOutputLength          integerValue
    dumpPacket               (1|yes|true|0|no|false)
    reverseEncodeBER         (1|yes|true|0|no|false)
    defaultPort              integerValue
    disableSNMPv3            (1|yes|true|0|no|false)
    disableSNMPv1            (1|yes|true|0|no|false)
    disableSNMPv2c           (1|yes|true|0|no|false)
    defCommunity             string
    noTokenWarnings          (1|yes|true|0|no|false)
    noRangeCheck             (1|yes|true|0|no|false)
    persistentDir            string
    tempFilePattern          string
    noDisplayHint            (1|yes|true|0|no|false)
    16bitIDs                 (1|yes|true|0|no|false)
    clientaddr               string
    clientaddrUsesPort       (1|yes|true|0|no|false)
    serverSendBuf            integerValue
    serverRecvBuf            integerValue
    clientSendBuf            integerValue
    clientRecvBuf            integerValue
    sendMessageMaxSize       integerValue
    noPersistentLoad         (1|yes|true|0|no|false)
    noPersistentSave         (1|yes|true|0|no|false)
    noContextEngineIDDiscovery (1|yes|true|0|no|false)
    timeout                  integerValue
    retries                  integerValue
    outputPrecision          string
    defDomain                application domain
    defTarget                application domain target
    dontLoadHostConfig       (1|yes|true|0|no|false)
    defSecurityModel         string
    tsmUseTransportPrefix    (1|yes|true|0|no|false)
    defAuthType              MD5|SHA|SHA-512|SHA-384|SHA-256|SHA-224
    defPrivType              DES|AES|AES-128
    defSecurityName          string
    defContext               string
    defPassphrase            string
    defAuthPassphrase        string
    defPrivPassphrase        string
    defAuthMasterKey         string
    defPrivMasterKey         string
    defAuthLocalizedKey      string
    defPrivLocalizedKey      string
    defVersion               1|2c|3
    defSecurityLevel         noAuthNoPriv|authNoPriv|authPriv
    trustCert                trustCert FINGERPRINT|FILENAME   In agentx.conf and agentx.local.conf:
    agentxsocket             AgentX bind address
    agentxRetries            AgentX Retries
    agentxTimeout            AgentX Timeout (seconds)
    agentxperms              AgentX socket permissions: socket_perms [directory_perms [username|userid [groupname|groupid]]]
```

Which does not include `pass` or `pass_persist`. There is no "real good" documentation on the build parameters, but I was able to find [this net-snmp issue on GitHub](https://github.com/net-snmp/net-snmp/issues/187#issuecomment-712155902) which gave me the hint.

In BuildRoot, the "Build with these MIB modules" needs to have the following added:

```
agent/extend ucd-snmp/pass ucd-snmp/pass_persist ucd-snmp/proxy ucd-snmp/pass_common util_funcs/restart
```

Delete the `build/netsnmp-5.9` directory in the `buildroot/output/` directory to force a rebuild of that module. Rebuild Buildroot.

Now when running the command

```
snmpd -Dmib_init -H
```

Results in the following:

```
    Configuration directives understood:
      In snmpd.conf and snmpd.local.conf:
        authtrapenable           1 | 2              (1 = enable, 2 = disable)
        trapsink                 [-profile p] [-name n] [-tag t] host [community] [port]
        trap2sink                [-profile p] [-name n] [-tag t] host [community] [port]
        informsink               [-profile p] [-name n] [-tag t] host [community] [port]
        trapsess                 [-profile p] [-name n] [-tag t] [snmpcmdargs] host
        trapcommunity            community-string
        v1trapaddress            string
        agentuser                userid
        agentgroup               groupid
        agentaddress             SNMP bind address
        quit                     (1|yes|true|0|no|false)
        leave_pidfile            (1|yes|true|0|no|false)
        dontLogTCPWrappersConnects (1|yes|true|0|no|false)
        maxGetbulkRepeats        integerValue
        maxGetbulkResponses      integerValue
        avgBulkVarbindSize       integerValue
        pduStatsMax              integerValue
        pduStatsThreshold        integerValue
        injectHandler            injectHandler NAME INTONAME [BEFORE_OTHER_NAME]
        table                    tableoid
        add_row                  table_name indexes... values...
        agentxsocket             AgentX bind address
        agentxRetries            AgentX Retries
        agentxTimeout            AgentX Timeout (seconds)
        master                   specify 'agentx' for AgentX support
        agentxperms              AgentX socket permissions: socket_perms [directory_perms [username|userid [groupname|groupid]]]
        com2sec                  [-Cn CONTEXT] secName IPv4-network-address[/netmask] community
        com2sec6                 [-Cn CONTEXT] secName IPv6-network-address[/netmask] community
        com2secunix              [-Cn CONTEXT] secName sockpath community
        certSecName              certSecName PRIORITY FINGERPRINT [--shaNN|md5] <--sn SECNAME | --rfc822 | --dns | --ip | --cn | --any>
        snmpTlstmParams          snmpTlstmParams targetParamsName hashType:fingerPrint
        snmpTlstmAddr            snmpTlstmAddr targetAddrName hashType:fingerprint serverIdentity
        group                    name v1|v2c|usm|... security
        access                   name context model level prefix read write notify
        setaccess                name context model level prefix viewname viewval
        view                     name type subtree [mask]
        authcommunity            authtype1,authtype2 community [default|hostname|network/bits [oid|-V view [context]]]
        authuser                 authtype1,authtype2 [-s secmodel] user [noauth|auth|priv [oid|-V view [context]]]
        authgroup                authtype1,authtype2 [-s secmodel] group [noauth|auth|priv [oid|-V view [context]]]
        authaccess               name authtype1,authtype2 [-s secmodel] group view [noauth|auth|priv [context|context*]]
        rwcommunity              community [default|hostname|network/bits [oid|-V view [context]]]
        rocommunity              community [default|hostname|network/bits [oid|-V view [context]]]
        rwcommunity6             community [default|hostname|network/bits [oid|-V view [context]]]
        rocommunity6             community [default|hostname|network/bits [oid|-V view [context]]]
        rwuser                   user [noauth|auth|priv [oid|-V view [context]]]
        rouser                   user [noauth|auth|priv [oid|-V view [context]]]
        createUser               username [-e ENGINEID] (MD5|SHA|SHA-512|SHA-384|SHA-256|SHA-224|default) authpassphrase [(DES|AES|default) [privpassphrase]]
        dlmod                    module-name module-path
  **    pass                     miboid command
  **    pass_persist             miboid program
        proxy                    [snmpcmd args] host oid [remoteoid]
        sysdescr                 description
        syslocation              location
        syscontact               contact-name
        sysname                  node-name
        sysservices              NUMBER
        sysobjectid              OID
        skipNFSInHostResources   (1|yes|true|0|no|false)
        realStorageUnits         (1|yes|true|0|no|false)
        storageUseNFS            1 | 2              (1 = enable, 2 = disable)
        count_kthreads           0|1    0 to exclude kernel threads from hrSystemProcesses.0
        ignoredisk               name
        interface                name type speed
        ifmib_max_num_ifaces     IF-MIB MAX Number of ifaces
        include_ifmib_iface_prefix IF-MIB iface names included
        defDomain                application domain
        defTarget                application domain target
        sourceFilterType         none|acceptlist|blocklist
        sourceFilterAddress      host
        engineID                 string
        engineIDType             num
        engineIDNic              string
        interface_fadeout        interface_fadeout seconds
        interface_replace_old    interface_replace_old yes|no
      In snmp.conf and snmp.local.conf:
        extraX509SubDir          string
        x509CRLFile              string
        tlsAlgorithms            string
        localCert                string
        peerCert                 string
        alias                    NAME TRANSPORT_DEFINITION
        doDebugging              (1|0)
        debugTokens              token[,token...]
        debugLogLevel            (emerg|alert|crit|err|warning|notice|info|debug)
        logTimestamp             (1|yes|true|0|no|false)
        logOption                string
        mibdirs                  [mib-dirs|+mib-dirs|-mib-dirs]
        mibs                     [mib-tokens|+mib-tokens]
        mibfile                  mibfile-to-read
        showMibErrors            (1|yes|true|0|no|false)
        commentToEOL             (1|yes|true|0|no|false)
        strictCommentTerm        (1|yes|true|0|no|false)
        mibAllowUnderline        (1|yes|true|0|no|false)
        mibWarningLevel          integerValue
        mibReplaceWithLatest     (1|yes|true|0|no|false)
        printNumericEnums        (1|yes|true|0|no|false)
        printNumericOids         (1|yes|true|0|no|false)
        escapeQuotes             (1|yes|true|0|no|false)
        dontBreakdownOids        (1|yes|true|0|no|false)
        quickPrinting            (1|yes|true|0|no|false)
        numericTimeticks         (1|yes|true|0|no|false)
        oidOutputFormat          integerValue
        suffixPrinting           integerValue
        extendedIndex            (1|yes|true|0|no|false)
        printHexText             (1|yes|true|0|no|false)
        printValueOnly           (1|yes|true|0|no|false)
        dontPrintUnits           (1|yes|true|0|no|false)
        hexOutputLength          integerValue
        dumpPacket               (1|yes|true|0|no|false)
        reverseEncodeBER         (1|yes|true|0|no|false)
        defaultPort              integerValue
        disableSNMPv3            (1|yes|true|0|no|false)
        disableSNMPv1            (1|yes|true|0|no|false)
        disableSNMPv2c           (1|yes|true|0|no|false)
        defCommunity             string
        noTokenWarnings          (1|yes|true|0|no|false)
        noRangeCheck             (1|yes|true|0|no|false)
        persistentDir            string
        tempFilePattern          string
        noDisplayHint            (1|yes|true|0|no|false)
        16bitIDs                 (1|yes|true|0|no|false)
        clientaddr               string
        clientaddrUsesPort       (1|yes|true|0|no|false)
        serverSendBuf            integerValue
        serverRecvBuf            integerValue
        clientSendBuf            integerValue
        clientRecvBuf            integerValue
        sendMessageMaxSize       integerValue
        noPersistentLoad         (1|yes|true|0|no|false)
        noPersistentSave         (1|yes|true|0|no|false)
        noContextEngineIDDiscovery (1|yes|true|0|no|false)
        timeout                  integerValue
        retries                  integerValue
        outputPrecision          string
        defDomain                application domain
        defTarget                application domain target
        dontLoadHostConfig       (1|yes|true|0|no|false)
        defSecurityModel         string
        tsmUseTransportPrefix    (1|yes|true|0|no|false)
        defAuthType              MD5|SHA|SHA-512|SHA-384|SHA-256|SHA-224
        defPrivType              DES|AES|AES-128
        defSecurityName          string
        defContext               string
        defPassphrase            string
        defAuthPassphrase        string
        defPrivPassphrase        string
        defAuthMasterKey         string
        defPrivMasterKey         string
        defAuthLocalizedKey      string
        defPrivLocalizedKey      string
        defVersion               1|2c|3
        defSecurityLevel         noAuthNoPriv|authNoPriv|authPriv
        trustCert                trustCert FINGERPRINT|FILENAME
      In agentx.conf and agentx.local.conf:
        agentxsocket             AgentX bind address
        agentxRetries            AgentX Retries
        agentxTimeout            AgentX Timeout (seconds)
        agentxperms              AgentX socket permissions: socket_perms [directory_perms [username|userid [groupname|groupid]]]
```

Which now includes the `pass` and `pass_persist` directives. Hopefully this saves somebody a day of Googling that I wasted finding this.